# Upload file through WebApi fails for larger file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to upload a file using WebApi. The byte[] is 1.6MB. For some reason my model is serialised to null. I suspect it's the filesize because it works with smaller files. Any ideas?

This is what I'm using - where data is a model containing a byte[].

```
return HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<T>(requestUri, data)
                    .ContinueWith(x => Handle<R>(x.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you have to change `.config`

```
<system.web> 
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152"/>
</system.web>

<system.webServer> 
  <security> 
      <requestFiltering> 
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" /> 
      </requestFiltering> 
  </security>
<system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks @isxaker. That worked. Weird that it didn't allow 1.6MB, is there any harm in changing this value?

Comment: @newbie_86 It's OK. It's a sort of restriction. Configure for your personal intentions.

Comment: @Mike some other restrictions might exists. try to change IIS settings

Comment: I learned after extensive research that if the HTTP post goes over the hard IIS limit it is impossible to overcome.  I cant remember what the limit was.  My solution was to re-architect the solution to allow multiple posts rather then trying to handle all the data in a single post.  I never even needed to make these config change in order to do a small http post such as 1.6 MB.