# How to convert an image from a UIImageView to base64 in xamarin.ios?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uiimageview, base64

I am trying to convert the image inside of the UImageView to base64 so I can insert into the database . I have tried this function to convert it to byte array:

```
   public byte[] datareturn()
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                thisimageview.Image.AsJPEG().AsStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

and in code I use :

```
  string  x = Convert.ToBase64String(datareturn());
```

Comment: what is wrong with the code you have?

Comment: I get a base64 output but every time I try to insert it into the database and I get an error ```The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.```. Before you tell me to check my server, inserting images using my xamarin.android project works perfectly fine. I think its a problem with converting the image to base64.

Comment: I tried to copy one of the base64 outputs from xamarin.android and its working but converting it from this project gives me that error

Comment: What is the exception causing the 500?  It's unlikely that the db cares what format the data is in.  You should be able to easily test whether the base64 encoding is working.

Comment: Did you check the database to see what type the field is using?  Is it a string (or varchar)?  What is the maximum size of the field?  Is your base64 string larger than the max size?

Comment: @jdweng nvarchar(max) . as I said the same process is working on my android app so its not a database problem . here is what my x variable value looks like ```/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/4QDKRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABgESAAMAAAABAAMAAAEaAAUAAAABAAAAVgEbAAUAAAABAAAAXgEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAITAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAZgAAAAAAAABIAAAAA...``` . I get the images from the iphone simulator , could be something from those pictures?

Comment: An image has an ASCII header which include the image format.  It is possible that the format is not supported.  You can open the image with Notepad to see the ascii header.

Comment: if the main issue is a 500 on the server, you need to figure out what specifically is causing that before you do anything else.  Randomly trying to fix your code without first understanding what is causing the problem can be a huge waste of effort.

Comment: okay I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36503855/11306390