# ASP.NET Framework web app setting contract to null when file is "large"

Tags: asp.net, rest

I have an ASP.NET framework web application that processes documents and returns it in a template contract. If I send it a smaller document (143KB) it processes fine and sets the template contract properly (ie. template contract is not null):
[Template set properly for smaller file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhMrK.png)

If I try a larger file (5MB), it receives the request but the template contract is null:
[Template contract set to null for larger file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3JFK.png)

This is the code where the template object is recieved:

```
        [Route("v2/document")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult ReportsV2([FromBody] Template template)
        {
            if (template.Data == null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(template.ConnectionString))
            {
                if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
                {
                    LogDebugHeaders();
                    LogRawIncomingContent();
                }
                throw new ReportGeneratorException("Template not provided. Specify the Data or Uri element.");
            }
```

So when I use the larger file it hits the conditional statement and throws an error.
Ive also added the following lines to the following lines to the web.config but still got the error:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

This is the exception I get:

```
System.NullReferenceException


 HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=RESTfulEngine
  StackTrace:
   at RESTfulEngine.Controllers.ReportsController.ReportsV2(Template template) in C:\Jenova\restfulengine\RESTfulEngine\Controllers\ReportsController.cs:line 95
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.<GetExecutor>b__2(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Please include textual data as text, not as links to pictures of text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload file through WebApi fails for larger file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503772/upload-file-through-webapi-fails-for-larger-file)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I stumbled upon that earlier and it unfortunately didn't help for me

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the all relevant information. Include the attempts you've made to remedy the situation yourself so that others don't waste their time suggesting things you've already tried.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I accidentally put the <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152"/> in the wrong place. Thanks for the help!